# Vibration Sensor - Balancing Machine

Tags: sensor

Im' working on a balancing machine. this machine has two vibration sensors. (pizzo) my question is about that why this machine use two Sensors? this machine has an rotary encoder to detect disk angle.

i trying to read these signal by ADC card and using FFT bandpass filtering to calculate unbalanced mass on disk. for this algorithm i just use one of Vibration sensors. should i use second sensor?

[image: Machine schema]

Comment: Can you please provide a little bit more information about the equipment? Maybe the reason for two sensors is a technical one (?)

Comment: this machine use to finding unbalancing mass on plastic Fan. when fan placed on this system, Start the spinning speed about 1500 rpm. after a while, system shows unbalanced mass and it's angle.(like  1.21 gr at 305 )

Comment: Can the sensor output to be added together or subtracted?

Comment: This is what I thought it might be doing internally. Otherwise, the signal of the two sensors will have a constant phase shift depending on RPM. Are you sure that both sensors are mounted on **the same** axis?

Comment: yes, there are mounted on same axis. there is only phase shift between two sensors.

Answer (score -1):

Of course, the machine could be provided with three, four or more sensors, if the goal of the control unit is perform a balancing of the rotation. Actually three sensors should be the proper selection if the rotation is unconstrained in a biaxial plane, and two sensors, if constrained in a uniaxial direction.